# Why won't my canvas display (Android)?

Tags: android, line, paint, android-canvas

I'm fairly new to this whole graphics/canvas thing. All I'm trying to do is display a canvas with a line on it below some buttons. What have I done wrong? Here is my code:

```
public class Vectors extends Activity{

    VectorsView vectorsView;
    LinearLayout l;
    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vectors);
        vectorsView = new VectorsView(this);

    }

    public class VectorsView extends View{

        public VectorsView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.vectors);


            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas = new Canvas();

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
            vectorsView.draw(canvas);

            l.addView(vectorsView);
            setContentView(l);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the requested vectors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/background" 
         android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/vectors" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true">
         </ImageView>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button android:text="Choose Program" 
                android:id="@+id/bChsProgV" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true">
            </Button>
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/help" 
                android:id="@+id/ibHelpV" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:background="@null" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            </ImageButton>
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">
             <TextView android:text="Value" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#fffafa">
             </TextView>
             <EditText android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/etValueV" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="100dp" >
             </EditText>
             <Button android:text="Next" 
                android:id="@+id/bNextV" 
                android:layout_width="65dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
             </Button>
             <TextView android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/tvAnsValV" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             </TextView>
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal">
             <TextView android:text="Angle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#fffafa">
             </TextView>
             <EditText android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/etAngleV" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="100dp" >
             </EditText>
             <Button android:text="Prev" 
                android:id="@+id/bPrevV" 
                android:layout_width="65dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
             </Button>
             <TextView android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/tvAnsAng" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
             </TextView>
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >              
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="Degrees"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/rbDegV">
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Radians"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/rbRadV">
                    </RadioButton>
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout> 
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:text="Q2"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                            android:id="@+id/rbQ2V">
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:text="Q3"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                                android:id="@+id/rbQ3V">
                        </RadioButton>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="Q1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/rbQ1V">
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:text="Q4"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:id="@+id/rbQ4V">
                        </RadioButton>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout> 
            </RadioGroup>                                                       
         </LinearLayout>
         <Button android:text="Submit" 
            android:id="@+id/bSubmitV" 
            android:layout_width="75dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
         </Button>
         <TextView android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/tvErrorV" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#fffafa">
         </TextView>
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llCanvasV" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you show your vectors.xml?

Answer (score 0):

either you use the VectorsView in your vectors.xml - but then you will need to add a constructor with attributes

or

you add a container (e.g. LinearLayout ) in your vectors.xml and add your vectorsView to it via code - then the constructor you have is enough

Answer (score 0):

Your view hierarchy is defined by your XML.

Your setContentView() call makes the ScrollView that is your top-level XML element the root view of your view hierarchy.

The VectorsView object that you have created in code is not attached to that view hierarchy.  Since it is not in that hierarchy, it never gets displayed.  Its onDraw() code will never be called.

The calls to addView() and setContentView() inside your onDraw() routine are inappropriate.  The general order is to define your view hierarchy in code called from onCreate(), and then allow the OS to call your onDraw() methods throughout that entire hierarchy.

If you removed everything but the drawing-related commands from onDraw(), then you could see it by replacing your setContentView(R.layout.vectors) call with setContentView(vectorsView).  Of course, none of your XML-defined widgets would then be visible.

This page provides some additional information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html